# Obtaining a specific part of a line

Tags: bash, awk

I'm trying to obtain the version number of a specific program:

```
TEST="$(program --version)"
echo "${TEST}"
```

Output:

```
/pathway/to/program version 2.2.6
64-bit
Built on anitra.peabody.jhu.edu
Wed Jul 22 13:40:50 EDT 2015
Compiler: Thread model: posix
Options: -O3 -m64 -msse2  -funroll-loops -g3 -DPOPCNT_CAPABILITY
Sizeof {int, long, long long, void*, size_t, off_t}: {4, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8}
```

I want to find the line that contains 'version' and then store the following version number (2.2.6) into a variable. In the past i've done something like this:

```
Example=$(awk '/text to find/ && ! seen {print $1; seen=1}' < "$INPUT/Logs/${k}.txt")
```

When finding a specific line in an input file.

But i'm not sure how to do it when the lines are loaded into a variable first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Example=$(awk '/version/ {print $NF}' <<< "$TEST")
```

`$NF` is last column of a row.

Content of variable Example:

```
2.2.6
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `grep`:

```
echo "$TEST"|grep -oP 'version\s\K[^ ]+'
2.2.6
```

Answer (score 1):

echo $TEST |grep -i version |awk '{print $NF}'